# What is the Stone–Čech compactification of a dense set of $\beta N \setminus N$?

Tags: gn.general-topology, compactifications, stone-cech-compactification

1. Is the Stone–Čech compactification of a dense $G_\delta$-set $X \subset\beta N \setminus N$ homeomorphic to $\beta N \setminus N$? Here, $\beta N \setminus N$ is the complement of $N$ in the Stone–Čech compactification of $N$.
2. For every dense $G_\delta$ subset  $A \subset$  $\beta N \setminus N$, is it true that there is a dense subset $B\subset A $ such that $\beta B=\beta N \setminus N$?

Comment: For this problem, do you mean that $\beta N\setminus N$ $\textit{is}$ the Stone-Cech compactification of a dense $G_{\delta}$-set $X$ (i.e. $X$ is $C^{*}$-embedded in $\beta N\setminus N$) or simply that $\beta X$ and $\beta N\setminus N$ are homeomorphic as you have said?

Comment: @JosephVanName: that´s a good point. I should point out however that in the Corollary 1.5.4 mentioned in my answer it is actually proved that $\omega^*\setminus\{x\}$ can not be $C^*$-embedded in $\beta N$ and therefore cannot be homeomorphic to $\omega^*$.

Answer (score 8):

If you consider only complements of points, which are particular dense $G_\delta$-sets, the answer is independent of $ZFC$. The following results can be found in van Mill´s article in the Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology:

> **Corollary 1.5.4:**  $(CH)$ If $x \in \omega^*$ then $\omega^* \setminus \{x\}$ is not
>   $C^*$-embedded in $\omega^*$.

and

> **Corollary 2.5.3:** It is consistent that for some $x \in \omega^*$ we have that $\beta (\omega^* \setminus \{x\})=\omega^*$.

I don´t know if it is possible to prove in $ZFC$ that there is a dense $G_\delta$-subset of $\omega^*$ which is not $C^*$-embedded in $\omega^*$.